# Update table increasing every row by 1 from max

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, max

I'm trying to increase several rows `order` field by one while taking into account max value of that field.

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jobs`(
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
`order` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
PRIMARY KEY(`id`));

INSERT INTO `jobs`(`name`) VALUES("John"),("Steven"),("Marie"),("Clair"),("Richard"),("Rober"),("Barbara")

UPDATE 
    `jobs` AS `j1`, 
    (SELECT MAX(`order`) AS `max` FROM jobs) AS `j2` 
  SET `j1`.`order` = `j2`.`max` + 1
  WHERE `j1`.`id` > 4
```

It sets rows of Richard, Rober and Barbara to 1 and I want to be 1,2,3 and if I would execute it again I want them to be 4,5,6

I know It would be perfect if the column order would be auto_increment / unique but it can't be in this case.

Comment: There's no real need to store this information. You can calculate it on the fly. And calling a column `order` is just asking for trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use user defined variables then you can do so

```
UPDATE 
    `jobs` AS `j1`
cross join (
select @r:= (SELECT MAX(`order`) AS `max` FROM jobs)
) t
  SET `j1`.`order` = @r:= @r + 1
  WHERE `j1`.`id` > 4
```

[`Demo for single update`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc0c3/1)

[`Demo for 2 times update`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e8396c/1)